# Adicionando uma área área sombreada sobre um plot no R?

Tags: r, lattice, lubridate

Estou fazendo uns gráficos utilizando o R, e preciso fazer um destaque (área sombreada num determinado local), mas só consigo plotar. Segue a imagem que consigo gerar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O destaque tem que ser um retângulo que vai do eixo Y de 4 a 50 e o eixo X de 21 de maio a 31 de maio. Segue o código:

```
library(openair)
library(latticeExtra)
library(grid)
library(lubridate)

timePlot(mydata, pollutant = c("Nox"), ylab = "Concentração", xlab = "Período de estudo", smooth=TRUE, cols = c("black"))
trellis.last.object()+
layer(lpolygon(x = c(ymd("2018-05-21"), ymd("2018-05-21"), ymd("2018-05-30"), ymd("2018-05-30")), y = c(-20, 600, 600, -20), col = "blue", border = NA, alpha = 0.2), under = TRUE, rows = 5)
```

Se alguém souber, já agradeço!
Segue o documento que estou utilizando em [CSV](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak2pOptPmINYoz1Vufj57FD-JSL9?e=WpovPS).

Comment: Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duas coisas que mudei pra conseguir fazer o gráfico.

1. O eixo x tem que estar no formato `datetime` e não em `date`. Pra ficar no mesmo formato do eixo x do gráfico. Usei 11:00 como horário, mas serve qualquer um no dia que te interesse.
2. Tirar o parâmetro `rows`, ou colocar o valor 1, já que só temos um gráfico e o parâmetro serve pra restringir as mudanças a certas linhas de uma grade de gráficos.

   ```
   library(openair)
   library(latticeExtra)
   library(grid)
   library(lubridate)

   guaraperiodos <- read.table("guaraperiodos.txt", sep = ",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

   timePlot(guaraperiodos, pollutant = c("Nox"), ylab = "Concentração", xlab = "Período de estudo", smooth=TRUE, cols = c("black"))
       trellis.last.object()+
         layer(lpolygon(x = c(ymd_hm("2018-05-21 11:00"), ymd_hm("2018-05-21 11:00"), ymd_hm("2018-05-30 11:00"), ymd_hm("2018-05-30 11:00")), 
                        y = c(-20, 600, 600, -20), col = "blue", 
                        border = NA, alpha = 0.2), under = TRUE)
   ```

Comment: Deu certo!!! Muito obrigada pela ajuda!